# Return line including found string

Tags: php, html, line-numbers

Say I have an HTML document: (Excerpt below with line numbers)

```
30 - <div id="myDiv">
31 -   <span class="mySpan">Some Text</span>
```

I am using PHP:

```
$html = file_get_contents('myHtml.html')
```

I want to find the line number on which a string is found (Let's assume there's only one occurrence of the string in the document), and return the entire contents found on that line. For example,

```
getLine('myDiv'); //returns <div id="myDiv">
getLine('class="mySpan"'); //returns <span class="mySpan">Some Text</span>
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding `line` as the set of characters separated by a newline character ('\n'), you can explode the $html string as follows:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $html);
```

Then iterate each line while keeping a line count:

```
$lineno = 1;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strstr($line, $what_to_find) !== FALSE) {
        //Match
        echo "Line $lineno: $line\n";
    }
    $lineno++;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this for several thousand lines rather than foreach?

Comment: You could first get the position of the first occurrence of the needle using strpos($html, $needle) and then scan back and forth to find where the line starts and ends (i.e. look for \n). However, is it worthy? Have you tried if 'foreach' performs badly for files with 10k lines, for example?

Comment: I know it'll be between line `500` and `1000`, so I'll just use a `for` loop and start at 500. Thanks! :-)